# Ubuntu cannot see disk partitions when installing

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, system-installation, uefi, hybrid

I've got **Toshiba Satellite U50t-A-10H** with Win8.1 installed, UEFI, HDD 750GB + 32GB SSD cache.

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on it. I've split my disk, made 200GB free unallocated space and booted Ubuntu USB. I proceeded with settings to install Ubuntu and I've got to stop on the partition manager page where I needed to choose disk where it should be installed. Nothing was there. No drives, just blank window. When I clicked on some button or on Install button the whole installation window freezed.

Ubuntu partition manager in liveUSB Ubuntu alerts that there is something wrong with drives and wants to **fix** or **ignore** the problem. When I ignore it, it starts normally and sees the whole 750GB disk as one drive with **!** next to it.

Switching from UEFI to CMS mode doesn't help, same problem.

First I wanted to do dual boot but I'm OK with formating the whole disk and installing only Ubuntu. How could I do it? Does anybody know what the problem could be?

EDIT:
output `sudo fdisk -l` (if it helps):

```
Disk /dev/loop0: 1 GiB, 1115594752 bytes, 2178896 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk /dev/sda: 698.7 GiB, 750156374016 bytes, 1465149168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: F563326D-2568-11E3-982D-B69BBCB9388F

Device          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1        2048    2099199    2097152     1G Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda2     2099200    2303999     204800   100M EFI System
/dev/sda3     2304000    2566143     262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda4     2566144 1035055103 1032488960 492.3G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda5  1444655104 1465143295   20488192   9.8G Windows recovery environment

Disk /dev/sdb: 29.8 GiB, 32017047552 bytes, 62533296 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: A2D2106D-3D45-11E3-8254-5C514F51D303

Device     Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1   2048 23523327 23521280 11.2G Intel Fast Flash

Disk /dev/sdc: 14.9 GiB, 15997075456 bytes, 31244288 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xc3072e18

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1  *     8064 31244287 31236224 14.9G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can't see the disk in ubuntu at any version because all disk is has allocated ubuntu.
If we want to see whole disk space then go to system setting and its show all configuration of computer as well.

Comment: But how can I install Ubuntu when it doesn't see disk?

Comment: While you installing ubuntu from your system its asked how much you want to give space him so by default give him 100GB. And then follow instructions one by one.