# Dual boot: Cannot boot into Ubuntu after installation

Tags: dual-boot, uefi

I have spent roughly 3 days on this, and I hope someone can help me out.

I am new to Unix and Ubuntu. I followed some instructions for dual OS installation (shrink partition -> install using LiveUSB, set up swap and / -> finish successfully). Now I cannot figure out how to boot in the installed Ubuntu.

When I use LiveUSB and gparted to look at the partition, it shows Linux and all the partitions. But yeah, cannot boot into it.

I tried Boot-Repair recommended repair, doesn't work. Here is the result: http://paste.ubuntu.com/12364031/. I tried Boot-Repair advanced repair, check box "Backup ...." something. Then after restarting it said "No operation system detected". In both cases I turned off Secure Boot.

My BIOS boot order does **not** have Ubuntu, only has OS Boot Manager.

I have Windows 8 UEFI pre-installed. Only 1 hard drive. My laptop is HP.

Thank guys. I am appreciated any help.

Comment: Which ubuntu version did you install?

Comment: Do you have legacy OS boot enabled and UEFI boot disabled in BIOS?

Comment: I installed Ubuntu 15.04. And no, I have Legacy off and UEFI boot on I believe.

Comment: Try Legacy on and UEFI off.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a *partial* duplicate of this one (and other similar ones):

[How do I get my HP laptop to boot into grub from my new efi file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/244261/how-do-i-get-my-hp-laptop-to-boot-into-grub-from-my-new-efi-file)

In brief, your HP's firmware is broken and it can't remember the Ubuntu entry. There's a workaround, described in my answer to that question; however, since I wrote that answer, the relevant Boot Repair option has been moved to the Advanced menu, so you'll have to go looking for it there.

Also, I'm disturbed by lines 49-68 of your Boot Repair output:

```
Failed to read last sector (1069545470): Invalid argument
HINTS: Either the volume is a RAID/LDM but it wasn't setup yet,
   or it was not setup correctly (e.g. by not using mdadm --build ...),
   or a wrong device is tried to be mounted,
   or the partition table is corrupt (partition is smaller than NTFS),
   or the NTFS boot sector is corrupt (NTFS size is not valid).
Failed to mount '/dev/sda5': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sda5' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
Failed to read last sector (1069545470): Invalid argument
HINTS: Either the volume is a RAID/LDM but it wasn't setup yet,
   or it was not setup correctly (e.g. by not using mdadm --build ...),
   or a wrong device is tried to be mounted,
   or the partition table is corrupt (partition is smaller than NTFS),
   or the NTFS boot sector is corrupt (NTFS size is not valid).
Failed to mount '/dev/sda5': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sda5' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

A similar message repeats on lines 106-126, relating this time to `/dev/sdb1`. This may be related to the partition type identification for `/dev/sdb1`:

```
Partition    Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors System
/dev/sdb1             128     7,896,959     7,896,832 Intel Fast Flash (iFFS) partition (for Intel Rapid Start technology)
```

The iFFS/IRST is pretty bleeding-edge stuff, and I've seen few reports of it being used successfully with any Linux. A Web search turns up some posts about it, such as:

- [Howto run Ubuntu with UEFI and Intel Smart Response Technology](https://askubuntu.com/questions/308481/howto-run-ubuntu-with-uefi-and-intel-smart-response-technology)
- [Ubuntu cannot see disk partitions when installing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/577298/ubuntu-cannot-see-disk-partitions-when-installing)
- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2256136
- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2264831

I haven't read those threads in depth, but my suspicion is you may need to back up Windows (or at least your user data) for safety, disable this feature, fix your disk, and re-install Ubuntu.

***DO NOTHING WITH YOUR COMPUTER UNTIL YOU'VE RESEARCHED THIS AND TAKEN APPROPRIATE STEPS!*** This is the sort of technology that, when mixed with an OS that doesn't understand it (such as Ubuntu, it seems) could cause massive data loss. I could be wrong, but my instincts tell me that you're headed down the path toward losing all your data.